# Any way to set png export resolution in Visio 2003?

Tags: vba, visio

I am trying to export a page from a Visio document to a `png` file using Visio 2003. The [Export](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa224609%28v=office.11%29.aspx) method works, but I haven't found any way to set the desired output resolution.

The documentation mentions what it uses the defaults, but nothing on how to change them:

> The Export method uses the default
>   preference settings for the specified
>   filter and does not prompt the user
>   for non-default arguments.

In Visio 2010, it is possible to set these properties via [SetRasterExportSize](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/visio-help/HV080360535.aspx), but that property isn't available in Visio 2003.

So, my question:

Is there any way to set the png output resolution in **Visio 2003**?

Answer (score 2):

Not directly.  The Export method for 2003/7 simply respects the last settings that were used via the UI (ie File / Save As from memory) for a given session.

One workaround suggested in Graham Wideman's book (Visio 2003 Developers Survival Pack) is to use the SendKeys method, although as he points out this is not a very robust option.  For his book he created a COM component (DAKbdEventLib) that avoids some of the problems of SendKeys.  I not sure if the book is still available (it's still very relevent to Visio 2010), but you could have a look here:

http://www.diagramantics.com/v11dsp/index.htm

As you point out the ability to control export settings via code, only appeared in the api in the 2010 version.

Hope that helps

Best regards

John